# Скрытие/показ LinearLayout во время прокрутки RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-linearlayout

Есть  список `RecyclerView`, внизу которого прикручена панель `LinearLayout` и `FAB`, стоящий на границе между этой панели и выдвигающейся панели. Вообщем, лучше один раз увидеть...

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/toolbar_bg"/>

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swiper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/audio_list"/>

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/music_sheet"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/music_panel"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/sheet_door"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fab"
    app:backgroundTint="#527dad"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/container_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Ну и как это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`FAB` раскрывает/закрывает расширенную панель

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо сделать скрытие/показ панели при прокрутке списка. При скролле вниз должен сначала уменьшаться `FAB`, потом проваливаться панель. При скролле вверх панель должна выплывать снизу, потом увеличиваться `FAB`. Вообщем, `FAB` можно анимировать так, как я хочу, с помощью методов `show` и `hide`. Я не пойму как их анимировать по очереди, есть способ отдельно анимировать `FAB` при скролле, также я нашел [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566163/show-hide-linearlayout-when-scrolling-a-recyclerview). для плавания панели (ответ не понял, там `SnackBar` зачем-то). Есть способ повесить слушатель скролла, но это вообще не поможет. Как мне можно обьединить эти варианты и стоит ли вообще?

Comment: ищите по `coordinatorlayout behavior`, вот тут можете посмотреть как подобное реализуется с тулбаром(в вашем случае если перевернуть то это тот же тулбар)) ): http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

Comment: `Toolbar` расположен над списком, моя панель поверх поверх него снизу. Я думаю, это не то, что мне нужно

Comment: вы не поняли, по ссылке которую я привел все примеры приведены для тулбара, но что вам мешает посмотреть как это реализовано для него и натянуть это на свою панель, ведь поведение в принципе тоже - скрытие при скроле